# Keep an Image Always Centered Regardless of horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a title with an image, but I need it to stay centered regardless of the horizontal scroll. So pretty much keep it centered and move with the scroll so it's always showing.

I tried centering it and following a few examples I found in SO but none of them covers what I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please share the links you have already checked so we don't try to show you the same links again.

Comment: Yep fixed position is what springs to mind.

Comment: +1 for `position fixed`. Simplest and effective solution

Comment: Or a background image?

Comment: position: fixed; !!! unless you actually mean horizontal scroll instead of vertical.... hmm

Comment: @lawnlanders I actually did mean horizontal, my bad hehe. Just edited my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want fixed position:

```
img.centered
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px; /* Width of image /2 */
  margin-top: -100px; /* Height of image /2 */
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <img class="centered" src="..." />
</body>
```

Comment: An ID is preferred because the element is only used once.

Comment: Perhaps.  You can use the above on multiple images that are on a page that get shown/hidden based on user input as well.  So long as they are all the same size of course.

Comment: Indeed you could, but that isn't asked here. Therefore, an ID would have been a better answer to this specific question. :)

Comment: This will also keep the element centered on vertical scroll as well.  Not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the background fixing technique as described here:

Better example:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position-background-image

```
body    
{
    background:url(your-image.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-position:fixed;
}
```

Here is the live demo:

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-repeat.php

---

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

for example:

```
body
{ 
    background-image:url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the best way but it works:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; width:100%; Height:100%; overflow:scroll;  left:0px;">ContenContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentt</div>

<div style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;">Centerd stuff</div>
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/chZWR/

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/TmbTM/)**

JS

```
var center = function () {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    ww = $(window).width();
    ch = $('#center').height();
    cw = $('#center').width();
    t = wh / 2 - ch / 2;
    l = ww / 2 - cw / 2;
    $('#center').offset({
        top: t,
        left: l
    });
};

$(document).ready(center);
$(window).resize(center);
```

CSS

```
#center {
    position:fixed;
}
```

There is a small advantage to using this method, if you should need to change the size of the image or swap the image out for another, you won't need to adjust the positioning. All the calculations are done for you in the script.